# Join multiple tables and find minimum - without UNION

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables in structure as shown below

[image]

I would like to find the minimum amount based on itemids for each subject. This is what I tried but it isn't correct. Not sure how to check for items in multiple tables using `CASE WHEN`.

```
select
d.subject_id,
MIN(CASE WHEN (table_2.itemid IN (1,2,3,4) or table_3.itemid 
in (31,32,33,34)) THEN (table_2.amount or table_3.amount) end) 
as min_d
from table_1 d
left join table_2 cv
on d.subject_id = cv.subject_id and d.hall_id = cv.hall_id
left join table_3 mv
on d.subject_id = mv.subject_id and d.hall_id = mv.hall_id
where (mv.itemid in (1,2,3,4) or cv.itemid in 
(31,32,33,34))
order by d.subject_id
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below. I am looking for the logic that can be implemented in any dialect of SQL.

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? Please tag the right DBMS and remove all others

Comment: have you tried using cross join and sum?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ - No, I didn't know what is cross apply

Comment: what is the use of table1 and why you want to use that ?

Comment: Table 1 is the parent table. Whichever subject is present in table_1, we only find minimum for those subjects for given item_ids

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `UNION ALL`. (It has no performance expensive duplicate elimination.)

Comment: Can you guys help me with this post please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964182/how-to-skip-errors-while-defining-constraint-after-data-upload-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=65f200111b680b6fbb8623540c8a882b)

The idea: Calculate the minimum for both tables seperately and then take the least value of both minimums afterwards:

```
SELECT 
    t12.subject_id,
    t12.hall_id,
    LEAST(t12.amount, t3.amount)                                    -- 3.
FROM (
    SELECT                                                          -- 1.
        t1.*,
        MIN(t2.amount) AS amount
    FROM table_1 t1
    JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.subject_id = t2.subject_id AND t1.hall_id = t2.hall_id
    GROUP BY 1,2
) t12
JOIN (
    SELECT                                                          -- 2.
        subject_id, hall_id, MIN(amount) AS amount
    FROM table_3
    GROUP BY 1,2
) t3 ON t12.subject_id = t3.subject_id AND t12.hall_id = t3.hall_id
```

1. Joining the first table, calculating the minimum amount of the first table
2. Calculating the minimum amount of the second table
3. After joining both result, comparing both minimums

Answer (score 1):

I suggest joining the parent table `table_1` to a subquery which is a union of the second and third tables:

```
SELECT
    t1.subject_id,
    t1.hall_id,
    t2.min_amount AS amount
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT subject_id, hall_id, MIN(amount) AS min_amount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT subject_id, hall_id, amount FROM table_2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT subject_id, hall_id, amount FROM table_3
    ) x
    GROUP BY subject_id, hall_id
) t2
    ON t1.subject_id = t2.subject_id AND
       t1.hall_id = t2.hall_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Actually I wish to do it without `union` because my data is so so huge. It's size is something like 777234566 and more..

Comment: Upvoted for the effort and time. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @SSMK I had a slight problem in my answer, but keep in mind that we don't have your data in front of us, and it is _very_ hard to get it right the first time without any testing.  Also note, I don't see any easier or more performant way to answer your question without using a union.  Ideally, the second and third tables should be just a single table.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for your time. In my case, it is two different tables. I have only shown the commo n columns but there is a reason why they are different tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.subject_id, A.hall_id, MIN(B.amount)
FROM table_1 A JOIN 
(
 SELECT subject_id,hall_id,amount,itemid FROM table_2 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT subject_id,hall_id,amount,itemid FROM table_3 
) B ON A.subject_id = B.subject_id AND A.hall_id = B.hall_id
GROUP BY A.subject_id, A.hall_id
```

Comment: OP says that he does not want to use UNION

Comment: Exactly. You are right. without union is there a way?

Comment: upvoted for the effort and time. I am looking for non-union approach

Comment: I have shown only common columns here. I have different columns in both table_2 and table_3. and the data is really huge, I don't really wish to make up another huge table. Hence my requirement was without union

Comment: can help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964182/how-to-skip-errors-while-defining-constraint-after-data-upload-postgresql